# using after() properly in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, delay

What I am attempting to do is run another file (file1 process) , and while that file is running  I want to check the local directory for existence of a file. If the file doesn't exist then everything keeps running and check again in 30 seconds. If the file does exist I want to print the contents to a label and stop the file1 process.

My code below causes Tkinter to erase all of its  labels and freezes the GUI while the after delay occurs. Where am I going wrong ?

```
def turnOn():
  global proc
  if proc is None:
    window.after(5000,file_chk) 
    print('Starting Beacon')
    proc = subprocess.Popen(["python3", "/home/pi/FLBeacon/FLBeaconout.py"])
    label1 = Label(window,text ="Beacon is Running")
    label1.configure(bg='green')
    label1.place(x= 350, y=10, width=150)
    global  label2
    label2 = Label(window,text = full_message)
    label2.configure(bg='green')
    label2.place(x=50, y=90, width=550)

def file_chk():    
    filelist = ['FLBeaconRecieved.txt']
    while True:
        list1 = []
        for file in filelist:
            list1.append(os.path.isfile(file))

        if all(list1):
           #all elements are true
           file = open("FLBeaconRecieved.txt")
           data = file.read()
           file.close()
           Results = Label(window, text = data)
           Results.place(x = 50, y = 350)
           print('Beacon Stopped')
           proc.terminate()
           proc = None
           label1 = Label(window,text = "Beacon is not running")
           label1.configure(bg='red')
           label1.place(x= 350, y=10, width=150)
           label2.destroy()
           break
        else:
          #time.sleep(30)
          print("there is no file")




on = Button(window, borderwidth=2, text = "Start Beacon", width=15, pady=5, command = turnOn)
off = Button(window, borderwidth=2, text = "Stop Beacon", width=15, pady=5, command = turnOff)
on.place(x=215,y=300)
 off.place(x=380,y=300)


def stop():
   window.destroy()
   #Top.destroy()

b = Button(window, borderwidth=2, text="Update Beacon", width=15, pady=5, command=enter)
b.place(x=50,y=300)
b = Button(window, borderwidth=2, text="Exit", width=12, pady=5, command = combine_funcs(turnOff, stop))
b.place(x=250,y=550)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: how is this question different from your previous question about this same problem?

Comment: Please fix your indentation. Also the only function you seem to be calling with `after` is not included here, so how could we fix it? =/

Comment: you have an infinite `while` loop. While that loop is running, no GUI code can run.

Comment: Its not a lot different question except I am having a great deal of trouble trying to understand how to use after.

Comment: So how would one do a check for a file every 30 seconds  and not be in an infinite while loop?

Comment: somehow the function name got cut in the copy paste, I updated it to show the function that after is calling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a loop in `file_chk` to repeatedly check for the files you need, have the function check for the files just once, and reschedule itself if the files are not ready yet:

```
def file_chk():    
    # ... (note, there should be no "while True" loop any more)

    if all(list1):  # check the condition just once
        # ...
    else:
        window.after(30000, file_chk) # if it failed, reschedule yourself
```

Comment: I tried that but the GUI was still freezing....I was calling file_chk() from within TurnOn() and had the else step with the after function but the GUI would freeze when the after function executed.

Comment: If you had the infinite loop, then I'd expect the GUI to stop updating. But if you reschedule *and then exit*, you shouldn't have that problem.

Comment: Actually you are quite correct,  when the GUI was freezing it was the while loop causing the freeze. I have since removed it at tried your answer and it does work thank you!